# jquery get next input element value in <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have some piece of an html table which reads like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myclass" name="first_ele[]" value="100" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="anotherclass" name="secon_ele[]" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a piece of jquery that will get the value of the element that contains class "myclass" on keyup and I am getting the proper value.
I need to get the value of the next input element.
FYI , The table gets rows added dynamically.
My issue is I don't know how to point to the next available input element.

my jquery to get the element which has the class "myclass" is as follows.

```
$('.tInputd').keyup(function(){
    var disc = $(this).val();
});
```

your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if it helps, I am using jquery 2.0.3 and jquery ui 1.10.3

Comment: there is no element with class `tInputd`... also do yoy want the next input element with the same class

Comment: Hi Arun, sorry I had edited out some details to make it less complicated. it should be "myclass" instead of "tInputd"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
$('.myclass').on('keyup', function () {
    var disc = $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val();
});
```

or

```
$('.myclass').on('keyup', function () {
    var disc = $('.anotherclass').val();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. This works for elements that are not created dynamically. How can I apply this for elements that are created dynamiclly?

Comment: `$('table').on('keyup','.myclass',function(){/*code*/});` try this